# How to calculate the Equation 3.2.34 in the figure?

Tags: pr.probability

[check the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCbL0.png)

[image: check the image here]

> For any fixed $\mathbf v \in \mathbb S^{m-1}$, we have
> $$||\mathbf  v^* \mathbf a| - | \mathbf v^* \mathbf a' || \le | \mathbf v^* (\mathbf a - \mathbf a') | \le \| \mathbf a - \mathbf a' \|_2. \tag{3.2.23}$$
> So, the function $f(\mathbf a) = | \mathbf v^* \mathbf a |$ is $1$-Lipschitz.
> A quick calculation shows that for $\mathbf a \sim \operatorname{uni} (\mathbb S^{m-1})$, we have
> $$\mathbb E [ (\mathbf v^* \mathbf a)^2] = \frac 1m. \tag{3.2.24}$$

I am confused about the Equation 3.2.34, can somebody help me, thanks!

Comment: I don't know the notation. What does uni mean?

Comment: uni is probably uniform distribution

Comment: yes, uni denotes the uniform distribution on the sphere.

Comment: and $S^{m-1}$ is a $m$-dimensional unit sphere.

Comment: I have tried to retype your question based on the picture. (Here is link to the [revision after that](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/453422/8).) In general, it is better to type the question properly rather than rely on images. Some of the pointers given here might help: [How does one type mathematical formulas on this site?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3763) (You can edit it further if needed - but if the result is satisfactory, the picture can be safely removed.)

Comment: Is this from the book [High-Dimensional Data Analysis with Low-Dimensional Models](https://book-wright-ma.github.io/)? You should mention that in your text - to help potential answerers to get some context.

Comment: OK. thanks for your advice! And this question is in the page 80 of that book indeed.

Comment: These posts on [math.se] seem to be about a smilar problem:
[Variance of x_i chosen from uniformly distributed hypersphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3196145) and 
[Variance of $x$ co-ordinate of uniform random point on a circle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4293032) And perhaps also this on [stats.se]: [Covariance matrix of uniform spherical distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22764).

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful for me, but I need some more time to find the connections between them.

Answer (score 5):

All of this relies on the isotropy of the uniform distribution of a vector on the unit sphere. Align your coordinate axis with the unit vector $v$, so that $v\cdot a=a_1$. Then use that $\mathbb{E}[a_i^2]$ is independent of the index $i$, so that $m\operatorname{\mathbb{E}} [a_1^2] = \sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb{E}[a_i^2] = \mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^m a_i^2]=1$, hence $\mathbb{E}[v\cdot a]=\mathbb{E}[a_1^2]=1/m.$